# Callable<Void> as Functional Interface with lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, void, callable

I am just learning about new java8 features. And here is my question:

Why is it not allowed to use `Callable<Void>` as a functional interface for lambda expressions? (Compiler complains about returning value)
And it is still perfectly legal to use `Callable<Integer>` there. Here is the sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // works fine
        testInt(() -> {
            System.out.println("From testInt method"); 
            return 1;
        });

        testVoid(() -> {
            System.out.println("From testVoid method"); 
            // error! can't return void?
        });
    }

    public static void testInt(Callable<Integer> callable) throws Exception {
        callable.call();
    }

    public static void testVoid(Callable<Void> callable) throws Exception {
        callable.call();
    }
}
```

How to explain this behavior?

Comment: couldn't you use `Runnable` here instead if you don't have a return value? (I am not familiar with Java8 yet)

Comment: @Thilo:  One benefit of using Callable is that it returns a Future, which can be used for other purposes later, such as killing a task the runs too long.

Comment: Also Callable can throw unchecked exception while Runnable can't

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For a `Void` method (different from a `void` method), you have to return `null`.

`Void` is just a placeholder stating that you don't actually have a return value (even though the construct -- like Callable here -- needs one). The compiler does not treat it in any special way, so you still have to put in a "normal" return statement yourself.

Comment: Smart. I thought it just couldn't figure out which one it should call and the static functions should be generic to provide the parameter for Callable, but I guess not. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Yeah, nice. `return null` works fine, but simple `return` statement doesn't, and I can't understand why.

Comment: The compiler does not treat `Void` like `void`. It treats it like any other class, so you need to return some instance of `Void` (of which there are none), or failing that, `null`.